# ResponseType not available in MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, swagger, swashbuckle

I've been using `ResponseType` attribute from `System.Web.Http.Description` namespace. It helps swagger to generate the client side models. But this is now missing from MVC 6. Is there any other attribute which has replaced this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a great article about everything dot net core for asp.net https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger.html

But to get you started try the ProducesResponseType attribute.